# Error with CNN-LSTM on Keras: ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3

Tags: conv-neural-network, lstm, tf.keras

I was trying to create a CNN-LSTM model and I received an error message:

` ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 60, 10)

The part of the code that result in the error seems to be this:

```
n_steps = int(60)
n_features = int(10)


def create_model(n_steps, n_features):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=1, activation='sigmoid'), input_shape=(None, n_steps, n_features)))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
    model.add(LSTM(CellVar, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(CellVar, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(6, activation='softmax'))
    return model

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    dataset = dataset_split(time_steps = 60)
    print(np.asarray(dataset["Train_X"]).shape, " ", np.asarray(dataset["Train_Y"]).shape, " ",np.asarray(dataset["Test_X"]).shape, " ", np.asarray(dataset["Test_Y"]).shape)
    model = create_model(n_steps,n_features)

    opt = Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)

    callback_lr = C.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss',patience=3,verbose=0,mode='min')
    checkpoint = C.ModelCheckpoint(filepath='best_pool.h5',save_best_only=False, monitor='categorical_crossentropy', mode='min')

    model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=["categorical_accuracy"])
    history = model.fit(dataset["Train_X"], dataset["Train_Y"], epochs=EpochVar, verbose=1,validation_data=(dataset["Test_X"], dataset["Test_Y"]),callbacks=[checkpoint, callback_lr])
```

`
The traceback shows that the code exited at history = model.fit

May I know how I can resolve the ndim issue? I read some posts that said that Train_X, Test_X should be reshaped, but I do not know how I should go about it.`

I tried removing Flatten and the code exited at model.add(LSTM with the error message:

`ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, None, 60, 64)

Just to check, I tried having only one LSTM layer by changing create_model to the following:

```
def create_model(n_steps, n_features):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(CellVar, activation='sigmoid', input_shape=(n_steps,n_features)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(CellVar, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(6, activation='softmax'))
    return model
```

`

This model is fit with no issues or errors.